# NumberFormat won't respect .toFixed

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I need this format:

```
555.555.55,55
555.555.55,50 /* Note te extra zero */
```

I am trying like this

```
new Intl.NumberFormat("es-ES").format(current.toFixed(2));
```

But this prints out

```
555.555.55,5
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is how you're using `format`:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat("es-ES").format(current.toFixed(2));
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The call to `current.toFixed(2)` will return a `string` instance already with 2 decimal places.

The call to `NumberFormat.prototype.format` with a string instance will cause it to convert the string back to a number and then format it according to the `es-ES` culture rules, thus losing information regarding the fixed-decimal-places format.

Instead, instantiate `NumberFormat` with an `options` object specifying `minimumFractionDigits`:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat("es-ES", { minimumFractionDigits: 2 } ).format( current );
```

Remember to cache your `Intl.NumberFormat` object if you will be reusing it so you're not re-creating it every time:

```
const esFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("es-ES", { minimumFractionDigits: 2 } ).format( current );

async function doSomething() {

    const someNumericValue = await getNumber();
    if( typeof someNumericValue !== 'number' || isNaN( someNumericValue ) ) throw new Error( someNumericValue + " is not a number." )

    return esFormat.format( someNumericValue );
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks a lot... ( I discovered this function like yesterday.. haha )

Comment: And depending on the use case, you could set `maximumFractionDigits` to 2 as well (for instance, if the formatted string is used as a price).

Comment: I doesn't seem to work in IOS, `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl` any workaround ?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet what version of iOS are you using? `Intl` is a relatively new addition to ECMAScript/JavaScript.

Comment: I'm solving it for now, deteting IOS and appending https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.es , what do you think?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Safari 10 (released 2016) added support for JavaScript's `Intl` feature ( https://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization ) so that polyfill isn't necessary (and hasn't been for 4 years now, [even IE11 supports most of `Intl`](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esintl/)).